# The colors.xml file has no resources tag

Tags: android, android-studio, colors

Everything was working perfectly, but all of a sudden I'm facing this problem with every new app i build. no resources tag in the colors.xml file, I'm using Android studio 3.5.

[image]

i know i can just add colors, but why is this the case every time i create a new project

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an empty or incomplete colors.xml file?
If you don't need any colour resources yet, can you try removing that comment and including a `<resources/>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, nothing fixed the problem until i uninstalled android studio and the sdk.